# OpenCV imshow() in a loop to show image

Tags: c++, opencv, imshow

I'd like to create a C++ program with OpenCV which would allow me to continuously run a loop to ask a user what to do with an image. For example the user can enter a specific number to execute a command. The code I have as an example is:

```
int main()
{
    int choose = -1;


    for (;;)
    {

    cin >> choose;

    if (choose == 0)
    {

        Mat img = imread(fileName1);//, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); 

        if (!img.data)
        {
            cout << "Unable to load file." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            namedWindow(fileName1, 1);
            imshow(fileName1, img);
        }
    }
    else if (choose == 1)
    {
        Mat img = imread(fileName2, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        if (!img.data)
        {
            cout << "Unable to load file." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            namedWindow(fileName2, 1);
            imshow(fileName2, img);
        }
    }
}


waitKey(0);

return 0;

}
```

The window where the image is supposed to load is just filled with grey. I don't have any problems loading the image when it is not in a loop. Can anyone help me figure out why this causes a problem please?

EDIT: Of course, forgot the waitKey(0) although even if I did have that, when I go back to the start of the loop to enter a number the window that was opened crashes for some reason.

Comment: you need a waitKey(); after the imshow() (typical noob pitfall)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that your waitKey isn't in the for loop and you have to  another value that 0 like 10

Comment: `waitKey()` has to follow `imshow()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `waitKey` to get the pressed key instead of `cin`. Alternatively as said in the comments do a `waitKey(1)` after `imshow`.